# Want to write a trigger after UPDATE

Tags: mysql, trigger, log

I have writen a trigger which will log every data updation and will log `previous_value, new_value, field_name` and many more. But the problem is i have **77 fields** in my table. So, it's difficult to write `IF ENDIF` for each field so i want to know is it possible to write using loop?

I have tried so far::

```
BEGIN

IF(OLD.company_name != NEW.company_name) THEN
 INSERT INTO elm_activity_log (user_id, action_on, action, action_col, action_old_value, action_new_value, action_at, action_on_id) VALUES (NEW.updated_by, "company", "update", "company_name", OLD.company_name, NEW.company_name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), NEW.company_id);
END IF;
IF(OLD.company_first_name != NEW.company_first_name) THEN
 INSERT INTO elm_activity_log (user_id, action_on, action, action_col, action_old_value, action_new_value, action_at, action_on_id) VALUES (NEW.updated_by, "company", "update", "company_first_name", OLD.company_first_name, NEW.company_first_name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), NEW.company_id);
END IF;

END
```

Please help, or any suggestion will be very helpfull.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dynamic sql is not allowed in the trigger body,you can use a statement which runs through all the columns and builds the IF statements

```
SELECT CONCAT('IF(OLD.',COLUMN_NAME, '=NEW.',COLUMN_NAME,' THEN
 INSERT INTO elm_activity_log (user_id, action_on, action, action_col, action_old_value, action_new_value, action_at, action_on_id) VALUES (NEW.updated_by, "company", "update", "company_name", OLD.' ,COLUMN_NAME,', NEW.',COLUMN_NAME,', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), NEW.company_id; END IF;')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='yourTable' AND column_key!='PRI';
```

You can narrow the results even more, take a look at COLUMNS table if you want to filter based on column type or remove columns with keys and so on.I removed the primary key columns in the last condition for example.